# Graph Theory Path Problem

Tags: graph-theory, path-connected

> Let $G$ be a connected graph such that $δ(G)≥k$. Proof there exists a path $P$ of length $k$ such that $G-P$ is connected.

I am not sure how do I actually approach this question. Do I consider contradiction or inductive proof, if so how. Really appreciate it alot

Answer (score 1):

We will try to prove that the path (v1,v2,...,vk) exist for every vertex v1 in G.

Let v1 be a vertex in G, then deg(v1)≥k since δ(G)≥k.

next we will pick a vertex from the k possible vertices, let call it v2 again
deg(v2)≥k but we only have k-1 possible vertices we choose again a vertex v3 again deg(v3)≥k but we only have k-2 possible vertices.

since the graph is connected the path exists since their is a path between every pair of vertices.

Comment: Thank you so much. The part on the existence of the path is very clear. But how can we assert that graph G-P remains connected since the initiate graph is connected. Could you kindly help me out.

Comment: For instance  δ(G)≥1 then it clear if there is a path then G-P will not be connected but since P is of length 1 there is no path. Since  δ(G)≥k and path length is k G-P is connected.

Comment: Thank you so much. But is there a theorem that shows δ(G)≥k and path length is k G-P is connected?

Comment: Menger's Theorem does not answer this question. I actually don't even see the link between the post and the theorem. @edcharlie

Comment: Since δ(G)≥k the graph will have cycles (it only require δ(G)=1 to have connected graph more than only adds cycles to G) , G-P is a connected graph with some cycles deleted.